# Pass a class template as template argument

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

Is it possible to pass a class template (like `std::vector`, not instantiating it like `std::vector<int>`) as template argument? I want to write a type that checks whether a given type is an instance of  a given template. I know that the compiler doesn't allow to pass an uninstantiated template as-is but I wonder if there is a better workaround than what I got.

My implementation (note that I erase `TArgs` at the very bottom):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Instance, typename Template>
struct IsInstanceOf : std::false_type {};

template <
      template <typename...> typename Instance,
      template <typename...> typename Template, 
      typename... IArgs,
      typename... TArgs>
struct IsInstanceOf<Instance<IArgs...>, Template<TArgs...>>
    : std::is_same<Instance<IArgs...>, Template<IArgs...>> {};
```

This implementation works, but I have to instantiate the template with some type, ex:

```
IsInstanceOf<std::vector<float>, std::vector<void>>::value
```

The behavior is as expected but I wonder if there is any better, like

```
IsInstanceOf<std::vector<float>, std::vector<>>::value 
// since this is illegal
IsInstanceOf<std::vector<float>, std::vector>::value
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/WGiodw) is a link to an example.

Comment: Usually something along the lines of specialization or SFINAE-based approach would be involved, but you need to explain what your real problem is. No, not the problem of using "uninstantiated templates", as you describe them. It's the problem to which you believe the answer is to use "uninstantiated templates" so that's what you end up asking about, instead of your actual problem. Instead, try describing what the original problem is, here.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Originally I wanted to check if a function template argument is a `std::shared_ptr` of some type. But then I thought I could generalize it somehow (to include it in my utils library).

Comment: Would it not be more correct to say, "Pass a class template as a template argument"? Uninstantiated template doesn't make sense, and will therefore be hard to search for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, template <typename...> typename Template>
struct IsInstanceOf : std::false_type {};

template <
      template <typename...> typename Template,
      typename... TArgs>
struct IsInstanceOf<Template<TArgs...>, Template>
    : std::true_type {};

#include <vector>
static_assert(IsInstanceOf<std::vector<float>, std::vector>::value);
static_assert(!IsInstanceOf<int, std::vector>::value);
#include <string>
static_assert(!IsInstanceOf<std::string, std::vector>::value);
static_assert(IsInstanceOf<std::string, std::basic_string>::value);

int main() {}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/PTXl0KoxoJ2aFJfK